# How to add subscript/superscript to buttons label in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml, subscript, superscript

I need to add subscript or superscript and normal text to buttons label. But as far as I understand button's label property is simple label, if it was RichText it would be easy.
I need subscript/superscript + normal text. Also I can't use 2 labels in skin class, I can only have 1 label or 1 RichText in skin class because as far as I understand labelDisplay works only for one label in skin class. Plus my button isn't constant.

So guys any ideas on how to get that done for button?

Comment: Create a custom button component that uses RichText instead? Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found:

1. Download & install GG Subscript & GG Superscript TrueType fonts. You will need to restart Flash software after installed fonts.
2. Create a text field with Arial font embeded. Set the HTML property to true.
3. Create a dynamic text field with GG Subscript font embeded.
4. Create a dynamic text field with GG Superscript font embeded.
5. Use htmltext to set text to subscript or superscript like below:

   ```
   my_txt.text = "Adobe<font face=\"GG Superscript\">TM</font>"
   ```

This is old solution for text fields. `mx:Label` supports htmltext, it may work. I think.